# Memory Leak using boost::archive::binary_iarchive

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, memory-leaks

Deserialization is working, the problem is the memory leak.
I have already tried to delete the 's' pointer but there is a 'Targeting failure', I can not delete the pointer.

```
//Statment MySql
sql::Statement *_stmt = this->con->createStatement();
sql::ResultSet *_result = _stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY `match_seq_num` ASC LIMIT 1250");

while(_result->next()){
    std::istream *s = _result->getBlob("match_object");
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(*s);
    Match _match;
    ia >> _match;
    delete s;
}
delete _result;
delete _stmt;
```

The problem is to delete the 's' pointer after using `boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(*s);` to deserialize the information coming from mysql.

Comment: I never saw such a use of iarchive.    The error may be in your opaque function getBlob().

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need the delete.

If that poses a problem, you should fix that. Your update points at a likely culprit: the input archive takes a *reference* to the `istream` and could still access it in the destructor (in fact I think it likely that it does). Therefore, make sure it's gone before destructing the required resources:

```
//Statment MySql
sql::Statement *_stmt = this->con->createStatement();
sql::ResultSet *_result = _stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY `match_seq_num` ASC LIMIT 1250");

while(_result->next()){
    Match _match;
    {
        std::istream *s = _result->getBlob("match_object");
        {
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(*s);
            ia >> _match;
        }
        delete s;
    }
}
delete _result;
delete _stmt;
```

Comment: Oh I missed the part about "Targeting failure". Tell us more about the library that gives you `_result`. It should have documentation on how to deal with resource ownership/lifetime.

Comment: I've made some changes to the question to make the problem more apparent. From what I'm seeing, something continues to use the 's' pointer after using `boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia (* s);`